# Oops! you have loaded package pgf after bidi package

Tags: errors, bidi, xepersian

I keep getting this error in my TeXStudio:

```
Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package pgf after bidi package. Pleocument again. \begin{document}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Call the pgf package before bidi. (\usepackage{pgf} and then \usepackage{bidi})

Answer (score 10):

You are probably not loading `pgf` directly; it's more likely that you are loading `tikz` or `pgfplots`, or some other package that depends on `tikz`.  Just make sure you load this before loading `bidi`.  Since `bidi` modifies lots of package behaviour to work with RTL languages, it's generally best to load it last in the order.  You may not be even loading `bidi` directly either, but it gets loaded, for example when you set the language using the `polyglossia` package, or the `xepersian` package so you should load that later too.

From the `xepersian` documentation (**Section 2: Basics**):

> 1. `xepersian` should be the last package that you load, because otherwise
>      you are certainly going to overwrite `bidi` and XePersian package’s
>      definitions and consequently, you will not get the expected output.